# How to code a c program which autocompletes options and commands like any command like tar or ls?

Tags: c, linux, bash, command-line, autocomplete

Almost any command in linux is written in **C** or **Bash** (mostly c).

Some specific commands like ls & tar are written in C language. They have an ability to autocomplete commands and options like

```
ls -l
tar x
```

on hitting `<tab>`  key. I want to implement the same I have a very little idea about how they work, I've read about the `readline` library which helps us in autocompletion. But the thing is I haven't found any line like

`#include <readline/readline.h>` in the original [c file](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c) by GNU at github. I am curious about finding that and implementing autocompletion in real-time.

I have tried of getting some information about the readline library. But, I couldn't find much helpful. I would like to learn more about autocompletion in linux commands which are purely written in c.

Comment: autocompletion of a filename using tab is always done by the shell, usually bash on linux. It has nothing to do with the command you want to start. So if you write your own `my_program` and want to start it as `my_program file.txt` you have to do nothing. It will just work.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Bash uses programmable completions, which many tools use to register callbacks to complete arguments for commands. Filenames will work without that, but other arguments don't.

Comment: Readline helps *the shell* do command-line completion. `ls` itself is uninvolved; when it starts, it sees a list of arguments that *results* from any shell-based processing of the command line.

Comment: beyond file path completion, you have to tell the shell how to complete various invocations of your commands.  https://iridakos.com/programming/2018/03/01/bash-programmable-completion-tutorial